# form action add page search

Tags: javascript, java, php

I have a problem
I hope you understand I write English badly:
I created a search field that contains these two files
index.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
$keySesso = $_GET['sesso'];
$keyEta = $_GET['eta'];
$keyRegione = $_GET['regione'];
$keyFoto = $_GET['foto'];

//sesso
if(isset($keySesso)){
if ($keySesso == 2) {
$FemminaE="selected";
}else if ($keySesso == 1){
$MaschioE="selected";
}else if ($keySesso == 26){
$Gay="selected";
}else if ($keySesso == 27){
$Lesbica="selected";
}else if ($keySesso == 29){
$FemminaB="selected";
}else if ($keySesso == 28){
$MaschioB="selected";
}else{
$sessoN="";
}
}
//for total count data
$countSql = "SELECT COUNT(last_activity) FROM _core_members INNER JOIN  _core_pfields_content ON _core_members.member_id = _core_pfields_content.member_id  $whereSQL $keyRegione $CondizioneEta $CondizioneFoto ";
$tot_result = mysqli_query($conn, $countSql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($tot_result);
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);

//for first time load data
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM _core_members INNER JOIN  _core_pfields_content ON _core_members.member_id = _core_pfields_content.member_id  $whereSQL $keyRegione $CondizioneEta $CondizioneFoto ORDER BY last_activity DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body >



<div class="BloccoBaseBO">


<div class="container" id="BOcontent">


<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
<form method='GET' id='FormChattaCon' class='FormBase' action=''>
<select id="SelectedSesso" name="sesso">
<option value=""   <?php echo $sessoN; ?>>Tutti i generi</option>
<option value="2"  <?php echo $FemminaE; ?>>femmine (Etero)</option>
<option value="1"  <?php echo $MaschioE; ?>>maschi (Etero)</option>
<option value="26" <?php echo $Gay; ?>>Gay</option>
<option value="27" <?php echo $Lesbica; ?>>Lesbica</option>
<option value="29" <?php echo $FemminaB; ?>>Femmina (Bisex)</option>
<option value="28" <?php echo $MaschioB; ?>>Maschio (Bisex)</option>
</select>


<div class='ConFoto'>Con Foto: <input id="checkBox"  name="foto" type="checkbox"  onclick="javascript: submitform()" <?php echo $check;?>/> </div>


</form>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tbody id="target-content">


<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {




echo "<div class='bloccoUserOnlineBO'></div><li class='NomeBloccoB'>$MemberName</li>";


}; 
?>
</tbody>
</table> 
<nav><ul class="pagination">
<?php if(!empty($total_pages)):for($i=0; $i<=$total_pages; $i++):
            if($i == 0):?>
            <li class='active'  id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='pagination.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
            <?php else:?>
            <li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='pagination.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
        <?php endif;?>
<?php endfor;endif;?>
</ul>
</nav>

  </div>








</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pagination').pagination({
        items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
        itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme',
  currentPage : 0,
  onPageClick : function(pageNumber) {
   jQuery("#target-content").html('loading...');
   jQuery("#target-content").load("pagination.php?page=" + pageNumber);
  }
    });
});
</script>
  
 <!-- tab -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrolling-tabs.js"></script>
<script>
$('.nav-tabs').scrollingTabs();
</script>

 <!-- FlexSlider -->
<script src="http://www..it/info-user-global/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www..it/info-user-global/js/main.js"></script>
```

the second where it is recalled from the pages
pagination.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ILFREE_core_members INNER JOIN  ILFREE_core_pfields_content ON ILFREE_core_members.member_id = ILFREE_core_pfields_content.member_id  $whereSQL $keyRegione $CondizioneEta $CondizioneFoto ORDER BY last_activity DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {

echo "<div class='bloccoUserOnlineBO'></div><li class='NomeBloccoB'>$MemberName</li>";


};
?>
```

The problem is this
When I compile the form, the result appears only on the index.php page
When I push the buttons on the bottom pages linked to the pagination.php page, I reset the form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecqjB.png)

I can not fix it because the form data will stop at the index page but when I call the pagination.php file through this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pagination').pagination({
        items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
        itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme',
  currentPage : 0,
  onPageClick : function(pageNumber) {
   jQuery("#target-content").html('loading...');
   jQuery("#target-content").load("pagination.php?page=" + pageNumber);
  }
    });
});
</script>
```

I reset the form
Please help me
I hope I was clear
I also leave you an email, I am willing to pay for help
IlfreeIF@gmail.com

Comment: <script>
function searchFilter(pageNumber) {
    pageNumber = pageNumber?pageNumber:0;
    var foto = $('#foto').val();
    var sesso = $('#sesso').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'pagination.php',
        data:'foto='+foto+'&sesso='+sesso,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading-overlay').show();
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#target-content').html(html);
            $('.loading-overlay').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}
</script>

Comment: I entered this but if I click on the punch nn nothing appears

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what AJAX is for (AJAX can do the same .load() function can, but with more configurability):

1. http://www.seguetech.com/ajax-technology/
2. [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)